Método Autocomplete de Jquery UI no filtra
tengo un problema al usar autocomplete de Jquery UI, ya que al momento de escribir alguna letra me lanza las sugerencias con palabras completas y quiero que al escribir por letra se valla filtrando y solo me quede la sugerencia mas parecida.
Este es el codigo que tengo y que no entiendo en que estoy mal...
$("#sistema").autocomplete({
source: function (request, response) {

    $.ajax({
        url: "https://aplicativos.ags.gob.mx/ws_IDC_C/api/Sistemas/ListadoSistema",
        data: { "nombre": request.term },
        dataType:"json",
        type: "GET",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(request);
            console.log(data.sistemas);
            response($.map(data.sistemas, function (item) {
                return {
                    label: item.sistema1
                };
            }))
        },
        error: function (response) {
            alert(response.responseText);
        },
        failure: function (response) {
            alert(response.responseText);
        }
    });
},
minLength: 1
});



Deberias incluir el codigo de la API
